# How do I build a C++ project using Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, git

I cloned a git repository from github (a project called plumed) and in order to install it I used to execute the following commands from the terminal:

```
> ./configure --enable-debug
> make -j 4
> make install
```

After that checking that everything was ok I used to execute the command

```
> which plumed
> /usr/local/plumed
```

How can I do the same from Eclipse?
Building from eclipse looks like to execute the command "make all" that returns errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what I do, hope it helps.**

I make a *build* directory, `cd` into that and run *configure* from there. That will produce a `Makefile` in the *build* directory. Then I create a `Makefile` project in *eclipse*. Open the `Makefile`. Then, on the right hand side, in the *Outline* window you can select the make targets you want to use (`all`, `clean`, `install`, `uninstall` ...).

You can make several *build* directories for different configurations (build-debug, build-release etc...).

In fact I have a *script* for each build type that sets various build flags and calls `configure` with the relevant flags:

```
#!/bin/bash

top_dir=$(pwd)

PREFIX=${PREFIX:-$HOME/dev}
LIBDIR=$PREFIX/lib

WITH="$WITH --with-mysql=yes"
WITH="$WITH --with-speller=yes"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$LIBDIR/pkgconfig"
export CXXFLAGS="-g3 -O0 -D DEBUG"

rm -fr $top_dir/build-debug
mkdir -p $top_dir/build-debug

cd $top_dir/build-debug
$top_dir/configure $WITH --prefix=$PREFIX
```

In *eclipse* I always make the `--prefix` point to install within the `$HOME` folders so you don't need *root* privilege to install everything.